# "OSError: Initializing from file failed" when reading lots of docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, glob

I am reading in several years of data files from a directory then reducing the data to what I need and then putting it together in a single data frame, but I am getting an "OSError: Initializing from file failed", the key lines of my code are:

```
data_list = []
count = 0
for file in glob.glob("mydir"):
    # read in file and name 
    name = "events" + str(count)
    name = pd.read_csv(file, sep = '\t' )

    #code to reduce file

    count += 1
    data_list.append(name)

all_events = pd.concat(data_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when I use glob I have to do so like this:

```
for file in glob.glob('mydir/*'):
    # do something
```

Otherwise I don't get the filenames that are in `mydir`. That may be part of your problem. Otherwise what seems odd is that you are initializing `name` with `name = "events" + str(count)` then immediately overwriting it with a DataFrame. Not sure if that is the desired behavior as the initial `name =` would be frivolous.